# How Do we Know How Old the Universe Is?

Tags: cosmology, time, universe, space-expansion, big-bang

It is common [knowledge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang) that the universe is 13.8 ± 0.037 billion years - but how was this calculated?

Comment: It's a best fit to the $\Lambda$-CDM model, which includes a cosmological constant and cold dark matter. If the model is wrong, the number may be wrong. However, since the physics during all but the very first fractions of a second is fairly well understood (maybe with exception of neutrino masses and possible dark matter decay), the number won't change significantly if we should discover new high energy physics. I would venture to guess that the remaining uncertainty after that is mostly in the validity of general relativity.

Comment: This should not have been closed as a duplicate.